# how to pass array prepare statement parameter IN QueryRunner

Tags: sql, postgresql, kotlin

I am trying to run this query on QueryRunner.
`select name from some_table where id in (?)`

My code is

```
// val ids: MutableList<Int>
...
...
val query = "SELECT name FROM some_table WHERE id in (?);"
val result = QueryRunner().query(connection, query, ColumnListHandler<Int>(), ids.toIntArray())
```

and I got this error,

```
java.sql.SQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of [I. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
```